# Google maps Geo Code is showing Upto Street address but not actual place

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is the place that i need to map
"53719 Madison USA 5555 Odana Road Supreme Health and Fitness"

But using geocode Api "53719 Madison USA 5555 Odana Road"
i meam upto street address but not to actual place "Supreme Health and Fitness"

I need help to point to the actual location rather than only to street address

Answer (score 0):

if you know the location (the correct coordinates), use those to place the marker, not the results of the geocoder.

However, [the geocoder database](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_geo2.asp?addr1=53719%20Madison%20USA%205555%20Odana%20Road&geocode=1) seems to have the correct location in it (the link provided uses the v2 geocoder, but I believe the results from the v3 geocoder should be the same, and it looks like a "rooftop" accuracy geocode).